# Why Would reinterpret_cast<const char*> of a Class and of Its Pre-Initialized Member Int Be the Same While Any Other Type of Variable Isnt?

Tags: c++, casting

I got this from an online exam (http://www.interqiew.com/tests?type=cpp) and have been stumped for some time.

I just don't get it. It compiles and runs fine. I've modified the code to be more expressive of the weirdness.

CODE:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    A( ) : m_x( 3 ) { };
    static ptrdiff_t member_offsetA(const A &a){
        const char *p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a);
        const char *q = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a.m_x);
        const char *z = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a.m_y);
        const char *s = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a.m_s);
        std::cout << q << " VS " << p << " VS " << z << " VS " << s << std::endl << std::endl;
        return p-q;
    }
    static ptrdiff_t member_offsetB(const A &a){
        const char *p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a);
        const char *q = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a.m_x);
        const char *z = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a.m_y);
        const char *s = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a.m_s);
        std::cout << q << " VS " << p << " VS " << z << " VS " << s << std::endl << std::endl;
        return z-s;
    }
    static ptrdiff_t member_offsetC(const A &a){
        const char *p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a);
        const char *q = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a.m_x);
        const char *z = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a.m_c);
        std::cout << q << " VS " << q << std::endl << " VS " << z << std::endl;
        return q-z;
    }
private:
    int m_x;
    int m_c;
    char m_y;
    std::string m_s;
};

int main(){
    A a;
    std::cout << ( ( A::member_offsetA( a ) == 0 ) ? 0 : 1 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ( ( A::member_offsetB( a ) == 0 ) ? 2 : 3 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ( ( A::member_offsetC( a ) == 0 ) ? 4 : 5 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: Symbols will be represented by unique letters preceded by three X's. So all XXXS's represent the same symbol. Whitespace means nothing was printed there.

```
XXXA VS XXXA VS   VS XXXB

0
XXXA VS XXXA VS   VS XXXB

3
XXXA VS XXXA
 VS XXXF
5
```

How does any of this make sense?

Why would the casting for a class and a member int produce the same results? Wouldn't they be different? If they're the same, why would other member values be different?

Also, why would anyone ever use this?

P.S. Paste of actual output:

```
 VS  VS �@ VS �����

0
 VS  VS �@ VS �����

3
 VS 
 VS �
5
```

Comment: Can you just include the actual output? It'd be easier to understand than your code.

Comment: (Clarification: By 'code', I meant the code that you are using to represent the output, not your source code.)

Comment: Outputting those pointers via `cout` results in Undefined Behaviour: They're interpreted as null-terminated strings (because of their type), but they don't point to null-terminated strings. Even worse, most of them point to uninitialized variables. IMHO, it would make more sense to print the *addresses* those pointers store, by casting them to `void const*` before outputting to `cout`.

Comment: All this seems to be showing is that the offset of the first member is zero and the other members don't overlap... how is this news? What were you expecting?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: The pointer arithmetic (subtraction e.g. of `p-q`) is also Undefined Behaviour, since those two pointers don't point to elements of the *same array*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything strange here. It makes perfect sense.

For normal, non-polymorphic classes the address of an instance of a class will be the same as the address of the first member of that class. That's just what an instance of a class is; it's the sum of all its members laid out sequentially (the instance itself adds nothing, unless it's a polymorphic class, or has non-empty base classes.) This is (not exactly but almost) called an "standard-layout" class in C++ (*Note: the actual definition is obviously more complex.*)

In the case of the members inside a class (and in fact for all variables,) no two of them can have the same address. And in fact they need 1 or more bytes of memory (you know, to store the bits of their respective values inside them.) So it again makes perfect sense for the addresses for consecutive members be different.

You might want to check out this code (which I believe is more instructive):

(Note: beware that there is "undefined behavior" in my particular use of pointer arithmetic here, so this in not completely correct C++. But to my knowledge it works fine. It's here for demonstration purposes anyways, so don't use this in production!)

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename U>
ptrdiff_t Dist (T const * from, U const * to) {
    return reinterpret_cast<char const *>(to) - reinterpret_cast<char const *>(from);
}

class A{
public:
    A( ) : m_x( 3 ) { };
    void printOffsetsAndSizes () const {
        std::cout << "A: " << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this) << " (" << sizeof(*this) << ")" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  m_x: " << Dist(this, &m_x) << " (" << sizeof(m_x) << ")" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  m_c: " << Dist(this, &m_c) << " (" << sizeof(m_c) << ")" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  m_y: " << Dist(this, &m_y) << " (" << sizeof(m_y) << ")" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  m_s: " << Dist(this, &m_s) << " (" << sizeof(m_s) << ")" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int m_x;
    int m_c;
    char m_y;
    std::string m_s;
};

int main () {
    A a;
    a.printOffsetsAndSizes ();
    return 0;
}
```

which gives this output on Ideone:

```
A: 3213332880 (16)
  m_x: 0 (4)
  m_c: 4 (4)
  m_y: 8 (1)
  m_s: 12 (4)
```

Comment: By the way, it seems strange that this `std::string` is only 4 bytes!

Comment: @yzt Indeed, probably because libstdc++'s `std::string` is non-compliant (uses COW). Usually, the size of a `std::string` is *at least* three times the size of a pointer (length of the string, begin of buffer, end of buffer).

Comment: *"You might want to check out this code (which I believe is more instructive):"* It still contains the Undefined Behaviour of pointer arithmetic with pointers that don't point to elements of the same array.

Comment: @KerrekSB: in your code, `X` is not a standard-layout type, because its first member is of the same type as its base class. In my answer, I didn't want to complicate things up, as this was clearly a novice's question.

Comment: @dyp: Thank you for the clarification on the string. It's a shame that after three and a half years (of C++11,) their implementation is still non-compliant.

Comment: @dyp: Hmmm... Then how should I fix it (without using `offsetof`)? In any case, I would still argue that it is more instructive than OP's original code. Not to mention that it would practically work everywhere.

Comment: The gcc folks *can't* make `std::string` compliant. That would imply breaking the ABI. Hopefully, they'll make this break in the next major version. -- It might be impossible to "fix" the issue without `offsetof`. I'd still argue that such code is dangerous, if not flagged with a warning that it (theoretically) invokes UB.

Comment: @dyp: Of course the GCC devs could have fixed it! If breaking ABI was inevitable, they could have done it when they introduced the "std=c++0x" flag in the compiler command line. I'm sure this would have caused an uproar, but the loss of ability to link your libraries together always does. OTOH, I'm sure they are putting it off so they can batch the many breaking changes they must have on their to-do list together. All in all, I'm happy that I'm not a compiler or standard library dev!

Comment: @yzt: I understand your motives, but I'm not a fan of "lying to the students", i.e. of telling a non-truth for the sake of simplicity, which later requires the advancing learner to unlearn earlier lessons. Simplicity and simplification are great, but I always try to keep the facts correct. For example, here one might say: "For a so-called 'standard layout class', the address of an instance is the same as the address of the first member of that instance. To be standard-layout, a class mustn't be polymorphic, all members must have the same access level, and a few more technical conditions."...